# Symfony form edit

Tags: php, forms, doctrine, symfony

I use Symfony 3.

I have an entity (Book) that I can create and edit. So I have created two actions and forms to do this. But, I want to save historical of this change.

I have imagine a solution. Two Entity, Book and SubBook to inherit of BaseBook. SubBook is the history of all edit of Book and is linked by a field "parent".

```
public function editAction(Request $request, ...)
{
    $book = ...
    $form = $this->createForm(BookType::class, $book);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $subbook = new SubBook($book);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($subbook);
        $em->flush();
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

AppBundle/Entity/Book

```
class Book extends BaseBook {
    // ...
}
```

AppBundle/Entity/SubBook

```
class SubBook extends BaseBook {
    // ...
    public function __construct($book)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // ...
        $this->parent = $book;
    }
}
```

AppBundle/Model/BaseBook

```
abstract class BaseBook
{
    // ...
}
```

But my problem is that when I submit the edit form, my Book (`$book`) is automatically persist when I execute `$em->flush();` so it is updated even if I don't execute `$em->persist($book);`.

So, do you have any idea to do this ? or to solve this error ?

Thanks !

Comment: $em->detach($book);

Comment: @goto Thanks but the questioner has not responded and a one-liner with no explanation is not much of an answer.  Feel free to write your own answer and maybe add some details.

Comment: @Cerad http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266954/one-line-answers - Edit: Oops, didn't saw you were a 25k user xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally did this. My `Book` is the entity with last update and I save in an `SubBook` entity all values that have changed.

My `SubBook` entity is so almost like `Book` but all value (not changed) can be `null`. So I abandoned the model.

```
public function editAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $book = ...
    $form = ...
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
        $uow->computeChangeSets();
        $changeset = $uow->getEntityChangeSet($book);
        $subbook = new SubBook($book, $changeset);

        $em->persist($subbook);
        $em->persist($book);
        $em->flush();
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

AppBundle/Entity/SubBook

```
public function __construct($book, $changeset)
{
    // ...
    $this->parent = $book;
    foreach ($changeset as $key => $values) {
        $this->$key = $values[0]; // values[0] => Hold value, [1] => New value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$em->detach($book);`. You can find more information in the [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html)

Comment: Hugo's answer is why I don't like to spend time writing detailed answers to these sorts of question.  Who knows what they really want.